# Queries in loop - Connection lost - Node JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, loops, connection

I'm trying to execute a bunch of really big SELECT statements (each of them require several minutes to complete execution) in a while loop.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection(
{

    host: "host_name",
    user: "user_name",
    password: "password",
    database: "database_name"

});

con.connect();

while(arg1 < arg2)
{

    var query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE value=arg1;
    con.query(query, function (err, result) 
    {
        //Rest of code
    });
    arg = arg + 1;

}
con.end();
```

At first, it's working but soon, after a certain amount of time, the connection seems to be lost.

```
Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:109:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

After reading a few similar issues on Stack, I understood the cause thanks to the page of Mysql on Github :

> You may lose the connection to a MySQL server due to network problems, the server timing you out, the server being restarted, or crashing.

So to handle the possible disconnection, I tried to use this function, following the work of a previous post :

```
function handleDisconnect() {

    connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); 

    connection.connect(function(err) {              

        if(err) {    

        console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
        setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); 

        }                                     
    });                                     

    connection.on('error', function(err) {

        console.log('db error', err);
        if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {

            handleDisconnect();                         
        } 
        else 
        {                                     
            throw err;                                  
        }
    });
}
```

In the following code :

```
while(arg1 < arg2)
{

    handleDisconnect();       
    var query = SELECT * FROM table WHERE value=arg1;
    connection.query(query, function (err, result) 
    {
        //Rest of code
    });
    arg = arg + 1;

}
```

But I still get the following error message :

```
error when connecting to db: { Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:109:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
    at handleDisconnect (C:\Users\X\connection.js:182:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\X\connection.js:105:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3) fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' }
C:\Users\X\connection.js:213
                if (err) throw err;
                         ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:109:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\X\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
    at handleDisconnect (C:\Users\X\connection.js:182:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\X\connection.js:105:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Is there something I don't get or is there something that I should be aware of to succefully manage the disconnection ? I still have troubles in Node JS understanding how to handle the notions of synchronous and asynchronous functions, maybe my problem comes from here.

Comment: Are you sure that MySQL is configured to let you connect for that long? What happens if you create a new connection for every query?

Comment: @cwallenpoole I don't know for sure for the configuration of MySQL but when I try to write con.connect() at the beginning of the while loop and con.end(); right before the end, I get the following error message : 

Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.